# Simplify vue code - use const from methods in computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've not a problem but I'm curios to know if there a way to simplify this code:

ddd

In `canDelete()` I now need also `isOwner`. So I just copied the code from the `canUserApprove()` method, which works fine. I'm just wondering if there is a nicer way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Make the `isOwner` to a computed too. Then access it via `this.isOwner`

```
computed: {
  isOwner() {
    return isOrganisationOwner(
      getOrganisationName(this.client.id),
      this.sessionUser.name, this.organisations,
    )
  },
  canDelete() {
    return this.sessionUser.admin || this.isOwner || this.sessionUser.name === this.client.creator;
  },
},
methods: {
  canUserApprove(value) {
    const isSameUser = (this.sessionUser.name === value.creator);
    const isUserAdmin = this.sessionUser.admin;
    return ((isUserAdmin && !isSameUser) || this.isOwner);
  }
}
```